# How do I memoize the creation of JSX elements with useMemo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization, react-usememo

I have a function which essentially acts as a `.map` to create JSX elements out of a list. I wanted to verify that my chain of logic for the memoization is correct, and that I have understood the dependencies.

```
const createJSXButtons = useCallback((buttonList) => {
    const jsxList = [];
    for (let button of buttonList) {
      jsxList.push(<button isToggled={parentState}>{button}</button>);
    }
    return jsxList;
  }, [parentState]);
```

This way, when I execute something like:

```
const myButtons = createJSXButtons(['R', 'U', 'F']);
```

I would get 3 JSX buttons inside `myButtons`.

As you can see, `createJSXButtons` captures a parent state within a closure, and is added as a dependency to the `useCallback` to prevent stale data.

However, I would also like to memoize the creation of `myButtons`, how can I do this? My first instinct was to use `useMemo`, but I was hoping someone could verify my approach.

```
const myButtons = useMemo(() => {
  createJSXButtons(['R', 'U', 'F'])
}, [createJSXButtons]);
```

The idea is whenever `createJSXButtons` changes, which only happens when `parentState` changes, then and only then `myButtons` will change. And we need `myButtons` to change when the `parentState` changes to ensure that each button is correctly receiving the correct `isToggled` boolean.

Have I understood the above flow of logic correctly? Kindly note I'm not asking *how* to use `useMemo`, but rather if my chain of logic is correct, specific to this use case.

Comment: Something like that would be better with `React.memo`  not `React.useMemo`

Comment: Could you expand on how to use that here? I thought that was for memoizing entire components.